# 422 Unprocessable Entity FastAPI Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, backend

I'm implementing a simple FastAPI app with MongoDB.
When I call the endpoint to create a document in the database I get the following response:

```
"POST /create/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Endpoint:

```
# Create a document
@app.post("/create/")
def create_doc(doc: dict):
    result = collection.insert_one(doc)
    new_doc = collection.find_one({'_id': result.inserted_id})
    new_doc['_id'] = str(new_doc['_id'])
    return new_doc
```

Any way to solve this, please?

Comment: *"The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 422 Unprocessable Content response status code indicates that the server understands the content type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions."* -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422

Comment: In other words, check your request to make sure it is well-formed, and then check the way your Python code is processing the request to make sure it understands your request.  There may be additional tools like server logs you can use to isolate the problem.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've read about it and found that I must use this to make it JSON-compatible. But still got it wrong. Can you help me?
`json_compatible_item_data = jsonable_encoder(doc)
result = collection.insert_one(json_compatible_item_data)`

Comment: Check your code to see if it's throwing any exceptions or returning any error messages.  "422 unprocessable entry" doesn't really tell you much.